# Get "score" from JSON array

Tags: php, json

I got a response from the reddit API where the statistics from a link is made into a array. However, I can't figure out how to get the score-value from the response.

My current code:
http://pastebin.com/mH7udEKD

The response I get:
http://pastebin.com/N5smhxry

Comment: looking at the rsponse, I ass ume the 'likes' part is the score you're looking for, but this part of the array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should give you the score value:

```
$json_output['data']['children'][0]['data']['score']
```

Comment: Thanks, now I think I understand how I can grab values.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the only way to reach it is `$json_result["data"]["children"][0]["data"]["score"]`.. are you sure this is the way to pull what you want from the API?

Comment: Yes, the reddit API isn't that evolved yet and json is the most used so I probably should learn that.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the response. Looks like this should do it:

```
$json_output['data']['children'][0]['data']['score']
```