# Decoding json string from facebook graph api explorer in php

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, gd

I am using the graph api to get the profile picture of my facebook app user to a specified width and height.

The url:
http://graph.facebook.com/'.$userid.'/picture?width=180&height=220

This will return something in json like
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc1/c0.0.553.676/s320x320/998591_136374463234627_573810314_n.jpg", 
    "width": 262, 
    "height": 320, 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}

I wish to know how to decode that in php and most appropriately how to get the 'url' in the json string returned. Thanks for helping.
Note: I'll store the url in a variable in php, then use the url to imagecreatefromjpeg(GD library) and then use the image and merge it with another image.

Comment: PHP's decode command is `json_decode`. Once you've done that, the result is a standard array. From there, you can pick out the url. Use this as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447084/get-score-from-json-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use json_decode function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

It accepts the json string as a parameter and returns either array or an object

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then, access values like

```
echo $obj->a;
echo $array['a'];
```

Both will output

> 1

In your case you can access the url this way

```
$obj = json_decode($your_fb_result);
echo $obj->data->url;
```

OR

```
$array = json_decode($your_fb_result, true);
echo $array['data']['url'];
```

Specific to your situation,

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$userid.'/picture?width=180&height=220&redirect=false');
$array = json_decode($response, true);
echo $array['data']['url'];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Here is the code:
$userprofpicurl='http://graph.facebook.com/'.$userid.'/picture?width=180&height=220';
$array = json_decode($userprofpicurl, true);
echo $array['data']['url'];

It doesn't seem to work! :(

Comment: You firstly have to get the output of that URL. file_get_contents will do the trick. See updated answer

Comment: I checked your URL and it returns the image, not the JSON. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070603/php-recreate-and-display-an-image-from-binary-data for ways to display binary data as image or just pass the URL in the SRC attribute in IMG tag

Comment: This is the image URL itself. Just try <img src='http://graph.facebook.com/SOMEUSERID/picture?width=180&height=220'>

Comment: what if i use this url instead:
http://graph.facebook.com/100005862221464/picture?width=180&height=220&redirect=false

Comment: Works perfectly for me if &redirect=false is added. I updated the last code sample in my response

Comment: Ok so now it is working, thanks a lot bro!
it was not working because i was getting the userid in a variable $user_id whereas in the url i was appending userid as $userid!
Thanks again! :)